# How to read a sitemap using VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I have been trying to open the following XML file in VB.NET using the Linq library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://wegotflash.com/sitemap.xsl"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://wegotflash.com</loc>
        <lastmod>2012-02-19</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://wegotflash.com/cat/1/shooter/newest-1</loc>
        <lastmod>2012-02-19</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The code that I'm using works with normal XML files, but whenever I add the `xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` attribute to the root node, nothing is getting returned by the application. Here is the VB.NET code that is reading the XML file:

```
Dim XMLFile As XDocument = XDocument.Load(TextBox1.Text)
For Each url As XElement In XMLFile.Descendants("url")
    If url.HasElements Then
        MessageBox.Show(url.Element("loc").Value)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `sitemap.xml` has default namespace `http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9`. You should define `XNamespace`, then use it in queries, i.e.:

C# code:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
foreach (var element in XMLFile.Descendants(ns + "url"))
{
    ...
}
```